# Как из формы передать файл в переменную функции?

Tags: php, form, phpexcel

Доброго времени суток. 
Есть форма:

```
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test02.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="fileExcel">
                    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

И обработчик Еxcel файла test02.php  (библиотека phpexcel)

```
            require_once('classes/PHPExcel.php');
            require_once('classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php');
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);

            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($_POST['fileExcel']);///Undefined index:fileExcel 

            $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">' . PHP_EOL;
            foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
                $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE);
                foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                    echo '<td>' .
                        $cell->getValue() .
                        '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
                }
                echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
            }
            echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Как из формы передать файл в переменную функции load()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш файл находится в другом массиве. Вместо $_POST['fileExcel'] нужно использовать $_FILES['fileExcel'] (http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.files.php)
[tmp_name] - ссылка на файл.

Comment: Спасибо, Выдает ошибку..
`Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\testExcelLib\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 346 `... сама функция  `public function load($pFilename)
 {
  // Check if file exists
  if (!file_exists($pFilename)) {
   throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception("Could not open " . $pFilename . " for reading! File does not exist.");
  }`    мб кто-то связывался с этой библиотекой?  что то меня в ней, не есть комильфо.

Comment: А вы так делаете? $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($_FILES['fileExcel']['tmp_name'])?

Вообще правильно сначала загрузить файл к себе на сервер, не во временную папку, а затем уже подцеплять его. Иначе по окончанию работы скрипта, в случае, если принятый файл не был переименован или перемещен, он будет автоматически удален из временной папки.